# switch statement unclear output in c++

Tags: c++

Here is the programm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string add(string s, int n) {
 switch (n%3) {
 case 2: s = s + "A";
 case 1: s = s + "B";
 break;
 default: s = s + "C";
 }
 return s;
}
int main() {
 string s{"X"};

 for (size_t i{0}; i < 6; ++i)
 s = add(s, i);
 cout << s;
 return 0;
}
```

And I expected output: XCBACBA

But correct output is:XCBABCBAB

Can you explain me an algorithm? it seems, that i don't understand the logic begind switch statement(and how does absence of break after `case 2` influence on the result?)

Comment: If you don't put a break into your case statement the next case statement will also be executed.

Comment: Perfect time to learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: SO is not meant to be used as a tutorial service. Consider the following options: 1) Reading a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to understand how `switch` statement works. 2) Step through the code with a debugger, to figure out how  the code is executed line-by-line.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `break` after

```
case 2: s = s + "A";
```

There should be one just like

```
case 1: s = s + "B";
 break;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `break` statement is how you leave the `switch` statement. If you don't have it at the end of a `case`, it keeps running with the next `case`. So your code is effectively equivalent to:

```
switch(n%3) {
case 2:
    s = s + "A";
    s = s + "B";
    break;
case 1:
    s = s + "B";
    break;
default:
    s = s + "C";
}
```

That's why your output always has an extra `B` after `A`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, if you omit a `break` at the end of a `case` statement, execution will fall through to the next case.

In your code this means that for `case 2`, both `s = s + "A";` and `s = s + "B";` will be executed.